# How to get x, y, z coordinates on touch on screen in opengles surface view

Tags: android, opengl-es

[image]

Above is my screen.

There is surface view and in this surface view I put renderer and drawn a square
I want to get location vector x, y in screen.

Suppose when I click on white circle I need to get x, y coordinate of opengl surface view

Help me to solve this problem

```
    /**
 * Copyright 2010 Per-Erik Bergman (per-erik.bergman@jayway.com)
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.jayway.opengl.tutorial;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

public class FlatColoredSquare {
    // Our vertices.
    private float[] vertices = {
              -0.5f,  1f, 0.0f,  // 0, Top Left
              -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  // 1, Bottom Left
               1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  // 2, Bottom Right
               1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  // 3, Top Right
        };

    // The order we like to connect them.
    private short[] indices = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };

    // Our vertex buffer.
    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;

    // Our index buffer.
    private ShortBuffer indexBuffer;

    public FlatColoredSquare() {
        // a float is 4 bytes, therefore we multiply the number if 
        // vertices with 4.
        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        // short is 2 bytes, therefore we multiply the number if 
        // vertices with 2.
        ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2);
        ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        indexBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();
        indexBuffer.put(indices);
        indexBuffer.position(0);
    }

    public void FlatColoredSquare1() {

        // a float is 4 bytes, therefore we multiply the number if 
        // vertices with 4.
        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

    }


    /**
     * This function draws our square on screen.
     * @param gl
     */
    public void draw(GL10 gl,float x,float y) {

        vertices[0] = x;
        vertices[1] = y;

        FlatColoredSquare1();


        gl.glColor4f(0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.5f); // 0x8080ffff
        // Counter-clockwise winding.
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
        // Enable face culling.
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
        // What faces to remove with the face culling.
        gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);

        // Enabled the vertices buffer for writing and to be used during 
        // rendering.
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        // Specifies the location and data format of an array of vertex
        // coordinates to use when rendering.
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);

        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, 
                GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);

//      gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_LINES, 0, 1);

        // Disable the vertices buffer.
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        // Disable face culling.
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    }

}
```

Above is My Square object class

```
   /**
 * Copyright 2010 Per-Erik Bergman (per-erik.bergman@jayway.com)
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.jayway.opengl.tutorial;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import com.jayway.opengl.tutorial.mgraber.MatrixGrabber;

import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.util.Log;

public class OpenGLRenderer implements Renderer {
    private FlatColoredSquare flatSquare;
    private SmoothColoredSquare smoothSquare;
    public float x = 1.8f;
    public float y = 1f;
    private Point points;
    public OpenGLRenderer() {
        // Initialize our squares.
        flatSquare = new FlatColoredSquare();
        smoothSquare = new SmoothColoredSquare();
        points = new Point();

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer#onSurfaceCreated(javax.microedition
     * .khronos.opengles.GL10, javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig)
     */
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        // Set the background color to black ( rgba ).
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
        // Enable Smooth Shading, default not really needed.
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
        // Depth buffer setup.
        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
        // Enables depth testing.
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        // The type of depth testing to do.
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
        // Really nice perspective calculations.
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer#onDrawFrame(javax.microedition.
     * khronos.opengles.GL10)
     */
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        // Clears the screen and depth buffer.
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        // Replace the current matrix with the identity matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        // Translates 7 units into the screen and 1.5 units up.
        gl.glTranslatef( 0f, 0f, -7);
        // Draw our flat square.

        Log.d("yyy", String.valueOf(y)+"dd");
        flatSquare.draw(gl,x,y);
        points.draw(gl);



//      // Translate to end up under the flat square.
//      gl.glTranslatef(0, -3f, 0);
//      // Draw our smooth square.
//      smoothSquare.draw(gl);

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer#onSurfaceChanged(javax.microedition
     * .khronos.opengles.GL10, int, int)
     */
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        // Sets the current view port to the new size.

        Log.d("hhhwidthhhh", String.valueOf(width));
        Log.d("hhhheight", String.valueOf(height));

        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        // Select the projection matrix
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        // Reset the projection matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        // Calculate the aspect ratio of the window
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float) width / (float) height, 0.1f,
                100.0f);
        // Select the modelview matrix
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        // Reset the modelview matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }




}
```

Above is My "Renderer" class

I actually want to get xy coordinate in rendarer class

Comment: Can you share some code to show what you've tried so far? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want x,y or x,y,z?

Comment: i only want x,y but i think opengl provides x,y,z by default